# git hooks : is there a clone hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-clone

We want to store some meta-information about the commit in an external database. During a clone or a checkout, this database should be referred and we copy the meta information to a file in the repo which is cloned. The database is required rather than just using a file is for the sake of indexing and searches etc ...

I thought if there is a clone hook, we could trigger this. I couldn't find the clone hooks in the sample in .git/hooks. is there one? is post-checkout hook the only possibility at client side?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ok, one way to do this is to use the `clone --template` option.

Specify the location where the client side hooks will be stored as value to the `--template` switch. The hooks are copied to the clone, and the post-checkout hook is fired immediately!

Comment: But the template directory cannot be inside the repository you are cloning - it must already exist on the filesystem before you clone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141577/1183537 helped me a lot, more clarification, and addresses what you said @chrishiestand

Answer (score 13):

When you *clone* a remote repository, you can't run any client-side hooks because hooks are local to your working copy, and you're creating one from scratch.  When you *pull* new changes from a remote repository, git will run your local `post-merge` hook if it exists.

There is nothing run on the server as the result of a *pull* operation.  A *push* operation will trigger the servers's `update` and `post-update` hooks.

See the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

No, there isn't any clone hook.

Answer (score 5):

Since git version 1.6.3, the **post-checkout** hook runs on git-clone (when run without `--no-checkout`).

> It is also run after git-clone[1], unless the --no-checkout (-n) option is used. The first parameter given to the hook is the null-ref, the second the ref of the new HEAD and the flag is always 1.

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout

Comment: This doesn't tell how to get the hook code added to .git/hooks or alternative for checkout

Answer (score 3):

I'm late but there is a workaround:

1. Capture `git clone` execution and set a variable using `trap set_var_on_git_clone DEBUG` where `set_var_on_git_clone` is a user-defined function. (e.g. https://gist.github.com/KeyAmam/a6afcabc3a724fc4a541aca7629c3ff6)
2. Check the variable in `post-checkout` script and do some stuff in the case. Clear the variable at the end of the script. (e.g. https://gist.github.com/KeyAmam/6a0e8805c0b6a662adb6bcf8118a089a)

This only works in Bash but you can do a similar thing in other shells.

Comment: Nice - I can add this to our machine setup Ansible script, and it will be easy enough to get it to detect and source .../.git_clone_hook, so the hook's under source control  like .gitignore.