# run bash script after git clone

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to run a simple bash script after a git clone was made, that checks the url of the repository origin and applies specific git-author settings.

this configuration shall be done on the local environment (not in the repository).

is there a configuration setting that I can apply to call a bash script after a git clone has completed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git hooks : is there a clone hook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook)

Comment: I need the same thing, but for Windows and Mac too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us say the bash script you intend to run is in a file by the name `shellscript.sh` and it is on your path:

You can add the following bash function to your `~/.bashrc`.

```
git() { 
   if [[ $1 == "clone" ]]; then 
      command git "$@" && shellscript.sh; 
   else 
      command git "$@"; 
   fi; 
}
```

Note: You can add any command after &&.

Comment: so every single machine to clone has to have this manually added?