# Is there a way to run a script inside a git repo immediately when that repo is cloned?

Tags: git

I want to be able to add the top level of the git repo to the PYTHONPATH immediately when it is cloned. Is there a way to do this? I have the following script in the top level of the repo:

```
#!/bin/bash
topDir=`pwd`
export PYTHONPATH=$topDir
```

And I need to run `source configure` at the top level. Is there a way to get this functionality immediately when the repo is cloned, rather than having to run `source configure` every time I clone or log in?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git hooks : is there a clone hook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook)

Comment: Yes I think that is what I am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck, I hope you can work it out