# init environment variables while run "git clone" from a remote repo

Tags: git, environment-variables, git-clone

How can I init environment variables while run "`git clone`" from a remote repo ?

Is there an option that when I clone the remote repo I can run a startup  file which will init
some environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really with git alone.

You *might* try a post-checkout hook, set up through a git template folder: see "[git hooks : is there a clone hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10546725/6309)".
But that is really tricky, and remains a local per-user solution.

You could consider a wrapper to the git command, which would, in case of a clone, export or set environment variables (again a local solution, not one associated with the repo you are cloning).

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I did is to create an hook of "post-checkout", that will init the environment variables.