# Github Webhook when somebody pulls code from my repository

Tags: github, webhooks

On the event selection screen on Github I don't see an option for "When somebody pulls code from your repository"

[image]

Such a webhook would make my work very easy I can automate creation of support tickets based on them for the clients who pull the code.

Is there any hook similar to that or can I add a web-hook of my own for this? Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available directly on the GitHub side, no more than there is a pull or clone hook  onthe server side (see "[git hooks : is there a clone hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10228978/6309)").

You can clone a GitHub repo without authentication, and that doesn't leave any trace on GitHub side (except maybe in Github own internal logging system, which is not related to Git)