# Can I add a note to self that is visible after repository cloning?

Tags: git

I just realized that I forgot to add a push hook to my freshly checked out repository and experienced some unpleasant consequences of that. I noticed that I cannot git add `.git/hooks/pre-push`. Can I somehow add a message to myself that will be displayed once I clone the repository that would remind me about adding the pre-push script?

Comment: Is this intended for your use only on your machines, or something others can use also?

Comment: @DarkFalcon: I guess that others could find it useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook) has information that may be useful for simulating git clone hook.

Specifically by tweaking post-checkout hook to create some hidden file if it doesn not exist and displaying the message. In future checks - file exists so no message.

Don't forget to add that file to `.gitignore` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a default-`pre-push`-script, containing the note, in a git-template-directory.

Amongst others the template-directory contains the hook-templates which will be copied to new repository, everytime the `$GIT_DIR` is created. And this is done everytime a local git-repository is initialized either by `git init` or `git clone`.

## Example

Although the documentation of [git-init](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) offers different options to define a git-template, i will create a custom template-directory in this example.

#### 1. Create a copy of the system-wide templates-directory

First of all we copy recursively a default template-directory to `~/.git-templates/` (you can name the directory however you want):

```
cp -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/templates ~/.git-templates
```

*I'm working with a Mac - so i found a (there were multiple directories) origin-template-directory at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/templates`, a Linux-user should be able to find the system-wide templates at `/usr/share/git-core/templates`.*

#### 2. Create a default-pre-push hook-script

Put a script like the following in the `~/.git-templates/hooks`, name it `pre-push` and make it executable:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf "\033[0;31m Note to myself:\033[0m don't forget to replace the pre-push-hook. :)\n"

exit 1 # this hook should always fail
```

#### 3. Refer to the new template-directory in your `~/.gitconfig`

Replace or add the `init.templatedir`-option, to make it refer on your new template-directory:

```
[init]
    templatedir = ~/.git-templates/
```

#### 4. Test your new default-pre-push-hook

Everytime you're now initializing or cloning a git-repository you should get the defined note.

> Please consider that the content of the origin template-dir may be change in the future, due to new releases of Git. In that case you might need to update the contents of your template-directory to eliminate nasty error-messages.