# Automatically do something after clone

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitignore, gitattributes

I'm using unity.
when I start a new project I should do this:

1. git init
2. Add .gitignore
3. `$ git flow init -d`
4. `$ git lfs install`
5. Add .gitAttribute

is there any way to do this automatically? like, write a shell script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git hooks : is there a clone hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+post-clone+hook

Comment: No, I want to do this manually not after clone, because I should create the unity project locally and then push it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand exactly what you mean but, assuming you are asking how to execute that series of commands every time you start a new project, how about creating an alias?

You can edit your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` file to have a custom command such as:

```
# Custom git initialization
alias custom-command='git init && touch .gitignore && \
git flow init -d && git lfs install && touch /path-to-attributes/.gitAttribute'
```

Now every time you run `custom-command` inside the terminal, it will run all of the above automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null || {
  git init &&
  curl -L -o .gitignore https://github.com/github/gitignore/raw/master/Unity.gitignore &&
  git add -A &&
  git commit -m 'Add .gitignore' &&
  git flow init -d &&
  git lfs install &&
  curl -L -o .gitattributes https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes/raw/master/Unity.gitattributes &&
  git add -A &&
  git commit -m 'Add .gitattributes'
}
```

Save it in a file like `unity-init.sh` and put it in `PATH`.