# Add remote to master repo and use the remote in all future clones

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

My problem is, I've added a remote of live to a current repo.

```
$ git remote add live ssh://user@myserver:port/directory
```

I've then pushed this repo to bitbucket and then cloned on another machine, however when clone the repo it doesn't have the remote settings that I put in the initial repository.

I have to add it every time, is there a way to add it so that it works across the board - or works within each repo that I add it to? Or am I doing something wrong when I add the live remote?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not doing anything wrong.

The ideal way to run a sequence of steps after a particular type of action would be to use a [`git-hook` for that action](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). However, that won't be possible here - there is no `git-clone hook` in `git` which could do that for you -- i.e.,automatically add a remote whenever a new clone is made for you.

Check out answers on [git-clone and post-checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141548/1860929) and [is there a clone hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook).

Basically, If you were cloning the same repo on the same machine again and again, then you could have used `--template` flag for the hook; However, since you are checking out the repo on different machines everytime, you will need to copy the template hook on each new machine, which is bad.

It is better that you run the command `git remote add live ssh://user@myserver:port/directory` everytime you clone the repository, from within the cloned repository.

You can then run `git remote -v` to check all the remotes available in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for that. It makes sense what've said there, thinking about it, it is probably better that it doesn't have the live remote on it so no one could overwrite the live site if they cloned the repo, sort of adds and extra level of security. Thanks for the reply.