# Set up more than one 'automatic' remote when cloning git repo

Tags: git, fork, clone

I would like to clone ('fork') a public git repository (residing, say, on GitHub) to our internal network **in such a way that whenever a developer clones that forked repository, they automatically get two remotes in their local repository**:

- `origin` (pointing to our internal, forked repository)
- `upstream` (pointing to the original, public repository)

### Example

Say we have a public repository at https://github.com/someone/foo.git

I'd now like to have a clone on our internal network at `internal-repos:foo.git`.

When the developer clones that repository `git clone internal-repos:foo.git`, they should have two remotes in their working copy

- `origin` pointing to `internal-repos:foo.git`
- `upstream` pointing to `github.com/someone/foo.git`

**Is that possible? If so, how can I do that?** AFACT `git remote` only operates on the local configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and add a post-checkout hook which would be triggered on a git clone.

That could be possible through the (shared and accessible by all) template folder, as described in "[git-clone and post-checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141548/6309)"

See the [Template section of the git init command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory): a `git clone --template=/a/shared/folder` could declare such a hook, which would then be in the cloned repo, and could add the missing remote.

Comment: Ah didn't know about git dir templates, thanks :) This still requires 'external' documentation. My users need to know that they have to include a template when cloning. :(

Comment: @ChristianKlauser yes, to be clear, there wouldn't be a full automatic solution, but that is at least a workaround.