# Git clone issue when symlink points into submodule on Windows

Tags: git, git-submodules, symlink, git-clone

Similar question was asked here, but it lacks investigation on why it happens, and answer is too generic:
[How to properly git clone with Windows symlinks pointing to folder in submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814310/how-to-properly-git-clone-with-windows-symlinks-pointing-to-folder-in-submodule)

Example repo: https://github.com/Zergatul/symlink-test

- I have submodule in the root in `java-scripting-language` directory
- I have symlink pointing into submodule directory `scripting -> java-scripting-language\src\main\com\zergatul\scripting`

When I run `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Zergatul/symlink-test.git` with enabled symlinks (core.symlinks=true), this happens:

- Git is cloning main repo first
- Git sees symlink. Now it depends on file system. NTFS has 2 types of symlinks: for files and directories. Unix-like file systems, such as ext4 or HFS+ have only single type of symlink, so for them Git just creates normal symlink. On Windows with NTFS Git checks the path where symlink points. If path points file, Git create file symlink, if path is directory - it creates directory symlink. If target path points to nowhere, Git creates file symlink by default. Since submodule is not here yet, Git creates file symlink.
- Git clones submodule
- Now file symlink is pointing to directory, making it invalid symlink in Windows

To fix I can checkout repository before symlink was added, and then checkout back to the HEAD:

```
git checkout 92b072cb536f4628eba0f9b70143e2010163ac58
git switch master
```

Above 2 commands fix symlink.

But can this be done more clean? Maybe it would be good if we can override default Git behavior and tell it to create directory symlinks if path points to nowhere? Old question proposes to setup clone hook, but it doesn't look nice for public open-source repo which is supposed to be easy to clone and build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git for Windows has a special extension in `.gitattributes` that lets you specify whether a symlink is a file or directory.  For example:

```
*.gif symlink=file
tools_folder symlink=dir
```

Note that this is ignored on other OSes, since they don't suffer from this problem.